# WPF Datagrid - Re-sizable RowDetails

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a need to make RowDetails inside a DataGrid re-sizable by the user (click & drag).  I am only interested in the height being re-sizable.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a gridsplitter in the DataTemplate for example:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- Content here -->
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndCurrent" ResizeDirection="Rows"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```